# Svg графика кроссбраузерность

Tags: jquery, svg, html, css, javascript

Из-за чего может быть? Во всех браузерах, кроме safari, работает нормально (svg картинки), если удерживать клик на фоне документа, то происходит transform: scale, в safari отображается не так как надо.

http://5ee03865.ngrok.com/

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать вот так:

```
canvas::selection {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Сафари на винде не очень популярный браузер (на Mac бага не обнаружил), поэтому если поможет, то почему бы не использовать такой костыль

Comment: Вроде не помогает...